# Are torsion modules always finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I was just wondering...are all torsion modules finite? Because, for instance, if the annihilator is (a), where a is nonzero, then all multiples of a are zeros...so that's like a cycle, right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^{\mathbb N}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The abelian group $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite and all torsion.